# Reset MongoEngine properly between tests

Tags: python, mongodb, testing, mongoengine, nose

I am wondering how to reset the MongoEngine state properly between tests or test files. It seems like dropping the entire database isn't enough. Given the following example:

```py
import unittest
from mypackage.models.domain.user import User                                                                        
from mongoengine import connect                                                                                  

class UsersTests(unittest.TestCase):                                                                             

    def setUp(self):                                                                                             
        self.conn = connect('test_database')                                                                     

    def tearDown(self):
        self.conn.drop_database('test_database')
        # User.drop_collection() # Uncomment to get expected results

    def test_something(self):                                                                                    
        print User._collection
        User(name='John H.', email='john@somedoamin.com').save()                                                 

    def test_something_else(self):                                                                               
        print User._collection                                                                                   
        User(name='John H.', email='john@somedoamin.com').save()                                                 

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                       
    unittest.main()
```

if I run it with nose (or nose2)

```
$ nosetests --notests/models/user_tests.py

None
.Collection(Database(MongoClient(None, None), u'test_database'), u'users')
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.685s

OK
```

Even if I run it multiple times, only the first User collection is set to None:

```
$ nosetests --nocapture tests/models/user_tests.py tests/models/user_tests.py
None
.Collection(Database(MongoClient(None, None), u'test_database'), u'users')
.Collection(Database(MongoClient(None, None), u'test_database'), u'users')
.Collection(Database(MongoClient(None, None), u'test_database'), u'users')
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 1.382s

OK
```

This behavior causes some hard-to-find bugs. After looking at the [source](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/document.py#L555-L562), it looks like Document class's `drop_collection()` is what I need for resetting the collection, but it's kind of weird to have to use it for all the collection in order to reset the MongoEngine state. Kind of wondering what the recommended way is. Any ideas would be super appreciated! Thanks!